# Pullback of a linear map on a 2-form.

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I am having a bit of trouble understanding a homework question and was seeking some clarification. Note, I have edited this question after I worked a couple of things out.

Given a 2-form $v=dx_1 \wedge dx_4+dx_2 \wedge dx_5+dx_3 \wedge dx_6$, I want to find an injective linear map $B:R^3 -> R^6$ such that $B^*v=0$.

So I was wondering, does $B^*v=0$ mean $v(B(x),B(y))=(dx_1 \wedge dx_4+dx_2 \wedge dx_5+dx_3 \wedge dx_6)(T(B(x)),T(B(y)))=0$ where $x,y \in R^3$ and T indicates the tangential derivative?

Assuming so, then $T(B(x))=B_i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}=\sum_k c_k B_i(x_k) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

So $B^*v=(dx_1 \wedge dx_4+dx_2 \wedge dx_5+dx_3 \wedge dx_6)(\sum_k c_k B_i(x_k) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\sum_n d_n B_i(v_n) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})
=\sum_k c_k B_1(x_k) \sum_n d_n B_4(v_n)-\sum_k c_k B_4(x_k)\sum_n d_n B_1(v_n) +4 similiar terms 
= \sum_k \sum_n c_k d_n (B_1(x_k)   B_4(v_n)- B_4(x_k) B_1(v_n))+ 2similiarterms=0$

But this is only true if  $B_1(x_k) B_4(v_n)- B_4(x_k) B_1(v_n)=0$. This condition also holds when 1 & 4 are exchanged with 2 & 5 and 3 & 6. Is this what the answer, i.e. $B^*v=0$ iff B satisfies these conditions or do I need a more explicit form? Furthermore, how do I prove that this map is injective?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for the structure of the functions $f_{ j }(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$, $j=1,...,6$ such that when you substitute $x_{j} =f_{j}$ that your two form vanishes.

Comment: I can offer a solution if you want more than clarification.

Comment: Oh and the map must be linear so $f_{j}=\sum_{ i=1}^{3}a_{ji}y_{j}$.

Comment: I suspect that the solution is not unique.

Comment: Hi, any chance of posting maybe the start of your solution so I can compare how it differs to mine above? (This is an altered version of the real question just so I can get a grasp of what's happening). I've used the fact that the map is linear but im just not sure how to determine more on the structure of B than what I did above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_{k}=x_{k}=x_{k+3}$, $k=1,2,3$

$$B^{*}v=dy_{1}\wedge dy_{1}+dy_{2}\wedge dy_{2}+dy_{3}\wedge dy_{3}=0$$

Now, there are a few remarks to be made. The image of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ under the map is not $\mathbb{R}^{6}$ but this should be expected. The best we could hope for by such a linear map is that the image is a 3-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^{6}$. The map will preserve distinctness but will not be onto $\mathbb{R}^{6}$.

Comment: Ahhh okay, so what I was doing above was correct, however I was doing it for the general case, where I only needed to find one injective linear map as the question asks.  Where you have given a specific linear map that holds true (as asked). Thankyou, that makes it much clearer!

Comment: Your welcome @Randy, and yes there will be many solutions to this answer.

Comment: To go one further,our tutor stated that this wasnt true if R^3 was replaced with R^4. Im trying to see that now, but i cant seem to work out why. Is it to do with the number of conditions on matrix A now causing the null space to no longer be trivial? I cant seem to write out the proof.

Comment: @Randy what did he say was not true? That there are non unique answers or that you can't force the pullback to vanish?

Answer (score 0):

In response to a comment you posed:

$$x_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{4}a_{ji}y_{i},\;\;\;j=1,...,6$$
Pulling back the given form I obtained

$$B^{*}v=\sum_{k,i=1}^{4}(a_{1i}a_{4k}+a_{2i}a_{5k}+a_{3i}a_{6k})y_{i}\wedge y_{k}$$

To make this vanish we respect the antisymmetric nature of the wedge product. All we need is for $a_{1i}a_{4k}+a_{2i}a_{5k}+a_{3i}a_{6k}$ to be symmetric when we replace $(i,j)$ with $(j,i)$. That is with an antisymmetric two form $y_{i}\wedge y_{k}$ and a symmetric coefficient we will sum over an antisymmetric summand. Said sum will vanish.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Isn't this proving that there is such a map from R^4 to R^6 whilst we are trying to prove that there is none such that A^*w vanishes? Apologies if i have misinterpreted.

Comment: @Randy no apologies needed. I was exploring it a little further and apparently there are many such maps that when the form is pulled back it will vanish.

Comment: Ah, but is the map injective?